# How to prevent npm install from installing my dependency's devDependencies?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I was using Node 9.3.0 and npm 5.6.0

I developed a library (let's call it Foo) which was hosted on GitHub. In its package.json, it has several devDependencies, but doesn't have any dependencies.

Then I created a new project called Bar and run `npm install my-github/Foo`. Instead of the single package, 140 packages were installed and all of them are Foo's devDependencies which are unnecessary for Bar.

According to several other questions, this should not happen. I tried `--prod` and `--only=prod` but did no change to the situation.

So, what is the problem?